# Google Analytics api v4 authentication with access_token from OAuth

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to follow the QuickStart example in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/data/latest

```js
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment this variable and replace with your
 *   Google Analytics 4 property ID before running the sample.
 */
// propertyId = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

// Imports the Google Analytics Data API client library.
const {BetaAnalyticsDataClient} = require('@google-analytics/data');

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Runs a simple report.
async function runReport() {
  const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: '2020-03-31',
        endDate: 'today',
      },
    ],
    dimensions: [
      {
        name: 'city',
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: 'activeUsers',
      },
    ],
  });

  console.log('Report result:');
  response.rows.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row.dimensionValues[0], row.metricValues[0]);
  });
}

runReport();
```

I have the GA4-PROPERTY-ID

I also have the access_token obtained from oAuth sigin so `Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable` doesn't work for me.

I want to use that access_token but don't know how to use it in this example code.

I am able to use it with a v3 request:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const analytics = google.analytics('v3');
const access_token = '..................';
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client();
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: userAccessToken });

const getAllProperties = (oAuth2Client) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = { auth: oAuth2Client, accountId: '~all' };
    analytics.management.webproperties.list(request, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(res.data.items);
    });
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated